# Remove all prompts and save to a specified folder in AcrobatDC?

Tags: adobe, ocr, acrobat

I am working with Adobe AcrobatDC and I need to OCR several images (PNG, EMF, JPEG) that are in a folder. I figured out how to create a batch process using the "Action Wizard" and it traverses the folder and creates text recognized PDF files. The only features I have not been able to figure out are how to automatically save the images into a specified folder. Currently my customized action will prompt me during he automation and ask if I "would like to save the file" and then prompt me again to "select a destination folder".

> ***Question:*** Using Adobe AcrobatDC action wizard how do I create a batch process in order to automatically save to a specified folder and
>   eliminate all prompts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "Save" step. In the options there, click the icon to the right of "Save". You can specify a local folder.

[image]

Comment: How do I do that ?